# Angular select multiple not setting selected items

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

Scenario is quite simple. I have edit view which comprises of select element with multiple selection. Select element looks as follows

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple
        ng-model="UserBeingEdited.UberTypes"
        ng-options="uberType.Id as uberType.Name for uberType in UberTypes"></select>
</div>
```

If I press edit for specific user then *showEditModal* function is called and edit pop up shows up. User has his own UberTypes objects selected so I pick theirs Ids and assign to UserBeingEdited.UberTypes.

```
$scope.UserBeingEdited = { UberTypes: []};

$scope.showEditModal = function (user) { 
     for (var i = 0; i < user.UberTypes.length; i++) {
            $scope.UserBeingEdited.UberTypes.push(user.UberTypes[i].Id);
     }
     $("#editUserModal").modal("show");
};
```

Unfortunately they are not selected, no matter what. Suprisingly, if I set values to property *UserBeingEdited* by the time of declaring then it works, items are selected.

```
$scope.UserBeingEdited = { UberTypes: [1,2]}; //this works
```

It seems like angular does not refresh selected items within UI.

**EDIT:** 
 I have two items: Uber1 and Uber2. Both items are selected but view does not reflect it. If I open drop down menu and select Uber2 it shows Uber1 selected, apparently Uber2 was selected and another click was treated as unselection. The same happens when I click Uber1 first, Uber2 shows as selected.

[image]

As above picture depicts, Uber2 is highlighted since I have just clicked it but it shows Uber1 as selected. Both were selected in User's UberTypes but view just simply does not mark them as selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/upusq8ah/7/ 
I use bootstrap-select.js for select element and presumably this library causes such an error since without including it, it works fine.

**Solution** 
After a while of struggle, I accidentally ran into below workaround. You need to call refresh on selectPicker and this **has to be delayed** otherwise it will bring no effect.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
       $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
 }, 100);
 $("#editUserModal").modal("show");
```

Comment: Try add setTimeout to delay the modal prompt.

Comment: Are you sure that `user.UberTypes` is not an empty array ?

Comment: setTimeout brings no change. I write console log and array is filled with items.

Comment: Try to delay sometimes for about 3 to 5 second. When the modal is showing, the array is not being completely filled. That's why the user is not selected.

Comment: I updated explanation. Despite 5 sec delay, still not working

Comment: Well, timeouts are pretty unstable because its depending on the user client performance. Its not a good idea to use timeouts. Well, I have an idea where you problem comes from but I need a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce it. Could you create one?

Comment: Sure, once I do I will get back to you.

Comment: @lin , its for debugging purpose only.

Comment: The image doesn't seem to depict a standard control. `<select multiple>` is not a dropdown. So the problem most likely is caused by a library you have included.

Comment: I added jsfiddle reference

Comment: I tried with ngRepeat but no such luck. You have jsFiddle, try it yourself. Once you succeed let me know.

Comment: I posted some workaround. Hopefully somebody may find it handy